# Python - ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cmd, import

I recently upgraded to the latest version of Python (3.7.1) for Windows. When I enter the command `python` in the command line, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named site.

The `py` command does work however.

`py example.py` will execute regular Python files and PyCharm works perfectly.

It has become an issue recently because when I go to launch the `py manage.py runserver` command for Django, I get the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you properly set up the path to python? `set PYTHONHOME=...`

Comment: I just allowed python to add itself to the path during the installation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System had been trying to execute python.exe from a different source to where my new Python installation was. I believe it was trying to execute the python.exe stored with my version of PgAdmin.

Fix:
Move Python environment variables to the top of system variables